# python statsmodels: "params" parameter for predict function of arima models

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

ARIMA (`statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA`), AR (`statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR`), and ARMA (`statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA`) in statsmodels all take in the parameters of their model in their `predict` method. For example, for the AR object, we have the following function definitions:

- `AR(endog, dates=None, freq=None, missing='none')[source]`
- `fit([maxlag, method, ic, trend, ...])`
- `predict(params[, start, end, dynamic])`

([Link to documentation here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.html#statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR))

I'm actually very confused about the parameter choices for `predict`. `predict`'s first parameter is the parameters to the constructor of `AR`; it doesn't make sense that these once again appear in the parameter for `predict`. They also appear for the constructors for `ARIMA` and `ARMA`. Can someone answer why this parameter exists?

For what its worth, I don't have much background in time series analysis, so perhaps there is some functionality that is exposed when reusing parameters. Otherwise, this parameter is a nuisance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered your question on the issue tracker [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2561). You want to call predict on the results object returned from fit. This the pattern that we follow.

```
model = sm.tsa.ARMA(y, (2, 2))
results = model.fit()
results.predict()
```